# Regex to replace part of a URL

Tags: regex, google-tag-manager

I have a url [www.example.com/au/shop](http://www.example.com/au/shop) that I need to build a regex function to replace the /au/ to /uk/. Not sure where to start, really appreciate the help here :)

Update: I need to use this in Google Tag Manager regex lookup table variable.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can start by saying which language you are using?

Comment: if that is all that is needed you don't need a regex at all, a simple replace of `/au/` to `/uk/` will work in any language.

Comment: Good question, I need to use this as a Google Tag Manager variable using Regex lookup table

Comment: I added gtm to the tags on your question. (Isn't that ironic?)  Getting tags right is important if you want a useful answer.

Comment: Every language/tool has a non-regex string replacement function/method,  eg python, java, javascript: `url = url.replace("/au/", "/uk/");`, PHP `url = str_replace("/au/", "/uk/", url)`, etc. They're all pretty much the same. What's the actual problem you are having?

Comment: @Bohemian, his problem is that he wants to use a built-in feature of Google Tag Manager that requires him to stick to certain conventions. General language advice is no help with that.

Answer (score 2):

Under *Variable Configuration* for the *Variable type* `RegEx Table` set

*Input Variable* to `{{Page Path}}`, *Pattern* to `\/au\/`, and *Output* to `/uk/`.

Make sure *Full Matches Only* is unchecked for this table variable to work.

Comment: I presume he does not literally want "uk" as output, but a path that has "au" replaced with "uk". So I guess he would need to capture the parts that precede and follow on the "au" and add them to the output.

Comment: @EikePierstorff That's exactly what GTM will do with above configuration – *a path that has "/au/" replaced with "/uk/"*. Think of it as *replacing* a regex match, no capturing required.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware!

Comment: You don’t need to escape forward slashes in regex.

Comment: @Bohemian `/` creates a regex literal in JavaScript, with escapes the pattern works both ways – as a literal or in a pattern string. Saves me time when moving patterns around.